# Excel Table Formula loses it's row alignment - Inconsistent calculated formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

[ROW***1059***] =IFERROR(INDEX(tbl_ProjectList[[#All],[Engineering Project '#]],MATCH(Journal!$***C1059***,tbl_ProjectList[[#All],[Project Name]])),"")

[ROW***1060***] =IFERROR(INDEX(tbl_ProjectList[[#All],[Engineering Project '#]],MATCH(Journal!$***C1061***,tbl_ProjectList[[#All],[Project Name]])),"")

0. The formula updates with the wrong row referenced.  ROW1059 is correct and represents what I've programmed.
1. I can force this to happen by sorting - This messes up the whole column
2. It does it on it's own - Typically only a few rows are affected randomly separated
3. It eventually realigns and then immediately loses alignment in the next row.
4. If I select the error box and select Restore calculated formulas it realigns properly
5. Sometimes the row misalignment is several rows apart.
6. O365 Excel Version 2102 (Build 13801.20360 Click-to-Run)
7. Windows 10 Pro

I'm referencing a table called ProjectList in another sheet in the same workbook. I'm matching it to a cell that is used to match to the ProjectList so I can pull information from the record to populate a cell in the Journal Table.

What am I missing?  What do I need to do to fix this.  It creates a headache when making sure the information I report to management is correct.

Thanks for the support.

Joe

Comment: Is it possible that rows are being inserted or deleted in one or other of the worksheets? If that is the case, you might want to put a short piece of VBA code in the Workbook_Open event to rebuild the formulas every time you open the workbook.

Comment: Which sheet is that formula on? If it's on the Journal sheet, then remove the sheet name from those references. In fact, if that formula is in a table, you should be using a table column reference rather than a simple cell reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response.1) Inserted or deleted - I'll pay attention to that.  2) Formula is in the table in sheet: Journal.  The referenced cell is (C1059) is the key to the correct row in the ProjectList found in a different sheet.  Rory, I applied your solution, replacing the cell reference with [@[Project Name]]. 
 =IFERROR(INDEX(tbl_ProjectList[[#All],[Engineering Project '#]],MATCH([@[Project Name]],tbl_ProjectList[[#All],[Project Name]])),"")  This seems to work.  I can't force it to fail.  Thank you.